# C# precisely show label for X seconds and hide it for Y seconds

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer, synchronization

I am writing a code for a form that should **precisely** blink a word Label.
It uses an "expositionTime" to **show a Label for X millisececonds** and an "intervalTime" to **hide it for Y milliseconds**.

The process will be repeated for Z times 'numExpositions' and starts after a button is clicked.
My code is working without errors, I am using two timers to do the work.
The problem is that **the timers get desynchronized** after some expositions.

**My question is if is there a solution that gives me precise time syncronization, where exposition time (show label) and interval (hide) will start and finish together - maybe using timers elapse on separate threads or monitor wait and how implement them.**

Part of my code using two timers:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer2;
private static int counter = 0;
private static int numExpositions = 16;
private static int expositionTime = 2000;
private static int intervalTime = 1800;

// starts both timers that get desynchronized after some time 
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { startTimer1(); startTimer2(); }

public void startTimer1()
{
        timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = expositionTime + intervalTime };
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTimer1Event);
        timer1.Start();
}

public void startTimer2()
{
        timer2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = intervalTime };
        timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTimer2Event);
        timer2.Start();
}

private void OnTimer1Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (counter >= numExpositions) // stops timers
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            timer2.Stop();
            wordLabel.Visible = false;
            counter = 0;
            this.Close()
        }
        else
        {
            wordLabel.Visible = true; // shows wordLabel
        }
    }

private void OnTimer2Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wordLabel.Visible = false; // hides wordLabel
}
```

Comment: I find the question unclear. Please explain why you are using two concurrently running timers in the first place. Why not just start one timer, and then when it has elapsed, start a second one? Why, since the intervals for the two timers are different, do you have any expectation that they would remain synchronous even after one iteration? What have you tried to attempt to address whatever synchronization issue you are concerned with? How is this question not a duplicate of the many existing questions on Stack Overflow involving timers and synchronization with a real-time clock?

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` are not that accurate. If you want accuracy try using `System.Timers.Timer` or `System.Threading.Timer`, you can find all the differences [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150329101415/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

Comment: @SimpleVar: though, none of those timer classes are 100% precise. Because they all have the contract that the timer will be fire no earlier than the given interval, but possibly later, and because they are all subject to the vagaries of Windows' thread scheduling, they will all have similar imprecisions. To be precise over a long period of time, code relying on timing needs to take into account an external clock (e.g. the computer's real time clock). Alternatively, one might choose to just use one timer instead, running multiple activities from that timer. It depends on the situation.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I agree. The `Forms.Timer` is *way* inaccurate though. I would also consider having only one timer, and work with it - it is the easiest and least limiting option, since the timers don't really have to be accurate as they just have to be synced.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I thought I should create the two timers independently so I could use them again in other processes. I tried to use lock instruction to sync them but it was also not successfull. The fact is that you are right, Forms.Timer is inaccurate for what I need. The easiest way to solve was using the the answer down here. I had also to add async to the button click method.
I will study more the case to understand and see if it won't give me any problems in the future. Thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to do this is as like this:

```
private async Task DoIt()
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numExpositions; i++)
    {
        wordLabel.Visible = true;
        await Task.Delay(expositionTime); //expositionTime is the number of milliseconds to keep the label visible
        wordLabel.Visible = false;
        await Task.Delay(intervalTime); //intervalTime is the number of milliseconds to keep the label hidden
    }

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoIt();
}
```

This requires you to use the .NET framework version 4.5 or later.

Comment: How does this address the OP's difficulty in synchronizing _two_ timed activities?

Comment: @PeterDuniho, as per his first sentence in the question, OP is trying to show the label for some time and then hide it for some time, and this is exactly what this code does. His attempt to use two timers will not give him what he wants as far as I understand his requirement.

Comment: All due respect, I don't think you can say _what_ the OP is trying to do. His problem description says _"after some expositions"_, not _"after a single exposition"_. The timers are already out of sync after a single exposition, so if that were all he was concerned about, surely that's what he'd have said. It's clear you're willing to make the assumption, but it's just that: an assumption. The code in your answer doesn't actually do the same thing that the OP's code does, and the OP hasn't been clear about just how far from the behavior he's got he wants to go.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, as far as I understand the question, the original requirement is to hide and show the label for specific time periods. The fact that OP choose to use two timers is just an attempt to meet this requirement. My answer is telling OP that he can meet his original requirement without using two timers.

Comment: @YacoubMassad In order for this to compile, you have to add `async` to the button click method.

Comment: @RonBeyer, I actually compiled and tested this :)

Comment: @YacoubMassad Thank you, your answer is really a better way and solved my problem until now. Forms.Timer is really inaccurate for what I need. I also had to add async to the button click method. Thank you very much :)